# Disable delete method by apache and nginx on elasticsearch

Tags: apache, elasticsearch

I want to disable Delete operation on my elasticsearch.From somewhere i get to know to make proxy my ES behind Apache or Nginx and configure it to deny all DELETE HTTP requests.
              I am unable to do that can please someone tell me how can stop delete method on my ES.

Below I have written in my config file:

```
       <VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin localhost
ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory "/var/www/">
 AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all


     <Limit  DELETE>
            order deny,allow
            deny from all
    </Limit>

</Directory>
```

If i am doing something wrong please let me know.
    Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1)Remove Directory code from above

2)Place this in httpd.conf file
Inside  <Location /> </Location>

```
<LimitExcept GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

It worked for me. Also make proxy of localhost:portnumber/index
Refer from this link if you want to learn to create reverse proxy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eshV2whJrqk

Comment: Please don't add YouTube links at the end of answers as it's commonly seen as self-promotional links and not allowed at Stack Overflow.